# Synaptics touchpad disable tap and doubletap on Windows 10 through Registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, touchpad

Upgraded Windows-7 to Windows-10, previous windows had ALPS driver package but now WinUpdate push Synaptics driver (v19.0.13.0). Unfortunately it does not bring wizard panel to set tap+doubletap+additional settings.

Windows only allow generic dialog values (swap left/right, mouse speed). Values set this registry values.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP
  MouseSpeedLevel=0..n
  EmulateMouseButtonSwap=0/1
```

I want to disable tap and doubletap features. I tried this [registry value](https://superuser.com/questions/729373/how-to-disable-tap-on-click-touchpad-on-windows/940569#940569) but did nothing. Do anyone has a working  Touchpad properties dialog and could identify registry value of Tap_on_touchpad=on/off and Doubletap_on_touchpad=on/off features?

[Lenovo has released Synaptics](https://superuser.com/a/949141/303050) Win10-64bit installer but Synaptics site does not give a generic installer. I don't feel comfortable to try this if Properties dialog was available again. Wish someone could dump Synaptics Registry tree and I could try direct registry values first.

edit: I have PackardBell EasyNote TJ75, added link to Lenovo.

Comment: PackardBell EasyNote TJ75 and puzzled me Win10 update pushed me Synaptics driver immmediately. I want to disable tap+doubletap features but unable to do so. DeviceManager/DriverDetails show it's synaptics dll driver. Was thinking it may use synaptics registry values.

Comment: Neither of those versions are event close to the current version.  Download the current version from Synaptics and/or the product specification page for your laptop.

Comment: Neither? I don't know version of ALPS dll (previous Win7) but Win10-upgrade after first reboot forcefully pushed Synaptics driver and no longer is properties dialog available. I can see this Win8 v17.0.19 link in synaptics site [link](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php#info_content) but no Win10 and WinUpdate gave 19.x. PackardBell site has years old win7 stuff only.

Comment: Found [link](http://superuser.com/a/949141/303050) telling Lenovo has released Synaptics v19.0.12.61 installer. Synaptics does not still provide a generic Win10 download link for some reason. Not comfortable to try Lenovo driver but maybe it's a last resort give Properties dialog if none has direct Registry values available.